# How to join 2 entities to get translated text in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 Code-First and I want my costumers to introduce new records in multiple languages. To store this I save all the texts in a Dictionary entity with a custom key and reference it from my other entity through this key.

This is a basic sample of my entities:

```
  Dictionary
    ID  Key          IsoCode    Value
    1   firstEntry   en-US      My new entry
    2   secondEntry  en-US      My second entry
    3   firstEntry   es-ES      Mi nueva entrada

  Entries    
    ID   Name         CreationDate
    1    firstEntry   2020-11-04
    2    secondEntry  2020-11-07
```

What I want to achieve is to query the Entries entity with an ISO Code, and get a new Entity where the Name field is replaced with Value field from the Dictionary entity.

This is what I have right now:

```
public List<Entry> GetEntries(string isoCode)
{    
    var query = (from e in dbContext.Entry
                 join d in dbContext.Dictionary on e.Name equals d.Key
                 where d.IsoCode == isoCode
                 select new
                 {
                    entry= e,
                    Text = d.Value
                 }).ToList();

    return query.Select(t => new Entry
      {
         Id = t.entry.Id,
         Name = t.Text,
         CreationDate = t.CreationDate
      }).ToList();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without creating two lists?
Is this approach of using a Key to get translated text a best practice or am I missing the point here?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach, altho with globalization you should be thinking on using a resx file, which is fine for most approaches. About your query if want to make it a "one line" you can remove the query.Select and append the code after the select new({}) and return without making a variable

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of your code using 2 lists instead of your tables (of course).

You can simply create the Entry in the first query. You don't need the `.ToList()` in that routine. Just return the `IEnumerable`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace JoinEntities
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Dict> dictionary = new List<Dict>
        {
            new Dict
            {
                ID = 1,
                Key = "firstEntry",
                IsoCode = "en-US",
                Value = "My new entry"
            },
            new Dict
            {
                ID = 2,
                Key = "secondEntry",
                IsoCode = "en-US",
                Value = "My second entry"
            },
            new Dict
            {
                ID = 3,
                Key = "firstEntry",
                IsoCode = "es-ES",
                Value = "Mi nueva entrada"
            },
        };

        static List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>
        {
            new Entry
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "firstEntry",
                CreationDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 04)
            },
            new Entry
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "secondEntry",
                CreationDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 07)
            }
        };


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = GetEntries("en-US");
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Entry> GetEntries(string isoCode)
        {
            return from e in entries
                   join d in dictionary on e.Name equals d.Key
                   where d.IsoCode == isoCode
                   select new Entry
                   {
                       Id = e.Id,
                       Name = d.Value,
                       CreationDate = e.CreationDate
                   };
        }
    }

    internal class Dict
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string IsoCode { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Entry
    {
        public object Id { get; set; }
        public object Name { get; set; }
        public object CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that using entities. That's the reason I'm using a second query.

Comment: Did you even try my solution?